# capacitance calculations

Tags: capacitor, relay

I am trying to calculate what size capacitor I need to energize a small relay coil for 5 to 8 seconds while the supplied voltage is removed momentarily . My supply voltage is 12 VDC, Relay coil draws 20 mA. The voltage rating for the coil is 9 - 40 VDC.

Comment: And what is the release voltage?

Answer (score 1):

Use C = I*T/deltaV

Assuming that the relay holds in until 9 V and starting from 12 V, you need
C = 20m*8/(12-9) = 53 mF. These are not readily available or practical. It is possible to get capacitors this large (supercaps), but they are generally only rated at 2.5 V.

You would be better to use a solid-state switch (MOSFET): start with a higher supply V (e.g. 40 V would allow you to use 20m*8/(40-9) = 5000 uF which is nearly reasonable (although quite large -- about the size of a soda can).

Comment: I agree with the higher voltage theme. 24VDC is such a common available supply voltage it is almost universal. Creating a longer time constant for discharge naturally seems better than splitting hairs over odd capacitor values.

Comment: Just a small language nitpick: since the topics of MOSFET and higher supply voltage don't have any connection, using a semicolon to join the sentences is inappropriate.